# Typecast from circularstring to polygon in postgis

Tags: postgis, qgis

How can i type typecast a CircularString Polygon or Multipolygon in PostGIS? I am doing so because CircularString Datatype is not supported by QGIS and i have to create a circle or ellipse, and it should get display on QGIS map canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ST_CurveToLine](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html) — Converts a CIRCULARSTRING/CURVEDPOLYGON to a LINESTRING/POLYGON

To create a polygon, use

[ST_BuildArea](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_BuildArea.html) — Creates an areal geometry formed by the constituent linework of given geometry